# Touchscreen-controlled dentist office snowman collector game

Tags: story-identification, video-games

In 2009-2012 I went into a dentist's office in the United States of America. There were a few touchscreen game systems. One of them had one of the [*Luxor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxor_(video_game)) video games, I think *Luxor 2* or *Luxor 3*. I looked at the names of all the games [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MumboJumbo#Games_developed) the same developer made and found none that seem to be about snowmen.

A very similar system there had this game:

- In it, there are a lot of snowmen running around in circles on some sort of icy-looking surface.

  - They were the kind of snowman with a carrot, coal eyes, and a coal mouth, like you see in movies.
- You can drag snowmen of the same height or smaller onto others to combine them. For example, a snowman made from one snowball could be dragged onto a two snowball snowman to make a three snowball snowman.

  - I think some of them were given hats if they got tall enough.
- When going between levels, which each had a goal such as "Make 4 three-snowball snowmen", the levels were represented as different snow globes.
- The snowman could at least get to be four snowballs tall; I didn't beat the game, so it might have gone further.
- I believe this game was targeted towards kids.

User Valorum has found a video of someone playing the game [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yTocifQRRE). As you can see, there's a bar marked "Magic" which would place this strongly on-topic for SFF.

[image: low quality screenshot of the game showing snowmen and various UI bars including one labelled "Magic" and one "Growth"]

Comment: This one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yTocifQRRE

Comment: @Valorum yes, that’s it

Comment: You guys have fun stuff at the dentist's. Here the only source of entertainment in the waiting room of any doctor are 15 years old pointless gossip magazines

Comment: @Jenayah - Sure, but aren't we all still intrigued to find out whether it works out between Emilio and Paula Abdul....

Comment: @Valorum I hate to tell you, but that's more like 30 years than 15.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is Megatouch Games' *Feeding Frosty*.

[image: Feeding Frosty screenshot showing snowman, gems and camp fires on the game board with igloos in the background and various UI elements across the screen]

Unfortunately, the products that played this game (the [Merit Megatouch Countertop Touchscreen range](https://www.bmigaming.com/games-catalog-meritentertainment.htm)) are now discontinued. You can pick them up on eBay or from specialist retro-gamer retailers but they're not cheap.

Comment: Just FYI, I found this by googling "Snowman touchscreen game" which led me to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yTocifQRRE). I then searched for other people who were talking about this video and found it referenced [here](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1169749). Although the poster didn't know the name of the game, they mentioned that they'd played it in McDonalds which led me to search for "Touchscreen game McDonalds Snowman" which led me to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_Bq__vqNyM) with the name of the game.

Comment: I've twitted at the rights-holder to find out if there is any way to still play it (e.g. any system that still has it) or whether it's available as an app. I suspect that the answer is 'no', but we'll see

Comment: This appears to be based on the game *[Feeding Frenzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feeding_Frenzy_(video_game))*, which has pretty much the same mechanics, but played as a fish instead. That game you can most certainly still find online.

Comment: @DavidK - The "*metroid-like only eat things smaller than you are*" game mechanic is a pretty common one found in a variety of 'aquarium games'. The ability to level up to win hats and use magic points as a smart bomb (to clear the screen when you're in a jam) is not found in any game other than Feeding Frosty, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Valorum "The ability to level up to win hats...is not found in any [other] game..." - except the wonderful SE Winter Bash! :P